# Server Group Lists not Updating on WSUS

Tags: windows, wsus

Good Morning everyone,

yesterday I created a new OU on the active directory and I moved a Server that was present on another OU into it (really simple task).
After almost 20 hours, on the WSUS server, in the group list of all servers/computers, the server that I moved in the AD is still present in the old OU and not in the new one.
What can I do? Do I need to run some command on the WSUS server to update the list?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: There is a possibility that the newly created OU doesn't have a different Windows Update target group related policy linked to it, and by default the same old one is getting applied on the old OU as well. Please check the linking of new WSUS policy to newly created OU with different target group in WSUS.

Comment: I've seen computers pull in GP updates after being moved across OUs but still hold the old WSUS target group. "GPupdate /force" and then "wuauclt /reportnow /detectnow" clears that up in minutes for me. The wuauclt is optional so you see it move WSUS groups quickly, but the GPupdate /force is required.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that client side targeting is still enabled and has the correct value, and that the client is also still configured with WSUS. You can do this via `gpresult /r /scope computer /v` or `RDoP.msc` or by checking the following registry keys:

   - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\WUServer`
   - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\TargetGroupEnabled`
   - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\TargetGroup`
2. The next time the computer contacts WSUS it will update the target group. The new target group must be added manually to WSUS, or the server will not register itself to that target group. You can speed up that process by manually searching for updates or invoking `wuauclt /ReportNow`. (Wuauclt was replaced by Usoclient in Windows 10. I'm not sure if it will work still on Server 2019 or Server 2016.)